# Let's get critical: Apr 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Gardening & Landscaping Stack Exchange](http://gardening.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: This was a great project, and I'll express a few thoughts in an answer. I think we did really well, and, as always, I'm proud to be a part of this community!  I did find a few questions in the group that could benefit from minor editing, but am not sure if I should change anything before people have had a chance to discuss the results. Would someone kindly advise?

Comment: @Sue, see [Should I improve posts that are part of the site self-evaluation or wait until the evaluation ends?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214761/should-i-improve-posts-that-are-part-of-the-site-self-evaluation-or-wait-until-t) and [On site self evaluations, is it OK to answer the questions before the review queue is closed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242789/on-site-self-evaluations-is-it-ok-to-answer-the-questions-before-the-review-que). Sorry, didn't see your comment til just now...

Comment: Thanks @J.Musser A quick meta search would have brought those questions right up-I should have thought to do that! As you know, most of the questions are fine, however, I would have fixed a few things if they weren't part of the eval. Also, according to my searches, some of the few that didn't receive "excellent" might have with a little tweaking.  No worries about getting back to me-I wasn't sure who would answer anyway. What did you think in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Can I force a dormant forsythia branch to bloom by bringing it inside?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/17473/can-i-force-a-dormant-forsythia-branch-to-bloom-by-bringing-it-inside)

**Net Score: 12** (Excellent: 12, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Grapes leaves too dry - is that normal?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/17395/grapes-leaves-too-dry-is-that-normal)

**Net Score: 11** (Excellent: 11, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Best way to avoid seedlings from bending and dying](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/16322/best-way-to-avoid-seedlings-from-bending-and-dying)

**Net Score: 10** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Is this compost bin rodent-proof?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/16309/is-this-compost-bin-rodent-proof)

**Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Can I give sugar (or something similar) to flowering plants?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/17469/can-i-give-sugar-or-something-similar-to-flowering-plants)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Can this plant be transplanted or is it too mature?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/17519/can-this-plant-be-transplanted-or-is-it-too-mature)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Plants that can be grown in USDA zone 8a](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/17423/plants-that-can-be-grown-in-usda-zone-8a)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How long before fruit tree grafts begin bearing fruit?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/17517/how-long-before-fruit-tree-grafts-begin-bearing-fruit)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [How can I mitigate azalea lacebug infestation without harming bees?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/16357/azalea-lacebug-mitigation-what-about-bees)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Am I over watering flowering plants](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/17510/am-i-over-watering-flowering-plants)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 4)

---